How to implement login with snapchat in flutter
I need help with to make login with snapchat button. I am implementing a app for a client and he need a button to login with snapchat. So, I researched and found there is a plugin called snapkit.
But it gives me error like this,

I want to know if this error fixable or is there any other way to do this? Or I just have to implement the method using native android and get back to the flutter using method channels?

flutter version: 3.22.0
dart version: 3.4.0

